# GLEW Odd Segmentation fault issue

Tags: c++, glew, glm-math

I have 6 models that I load and display in a window.  5 of them load perfectly, the transformations that I perform on them have no issue and the lighting looks great.  One Segmentation faults when I bind my VBO as narrowed down below:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &myVAO);
glBindVertexArray(myVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &myVBO);
cerr << "cerr" << endl;
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );  //Seg faults here
cerr << "made it here to 370" << endl;
```

GDB

> glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );
>   (gdb)
>   0x000000000040474e  369     glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );
>   (gdb)
>   0x0000000000404754  369     glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );
>   (gdb)
>   0x0000000000404756  369     glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );
>   (gdb)
>   0x000000000040475b  369     glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBO );
>   (gdb)
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000038c167e296 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Yes I include   `GLenum err = glewInit();`

Has anyone expierienced anything like this?

Comment: The error is not necessarily related to `glBindBuffer`. A reason for the segmentation fault happening at `_int_malloc`  might be that  you wrote somewhere into memory where you shouldn't, e.g. by using an uninitialized pointer or a wrong length for an _array_.

Comment: It's possible.  Very weird that it's the only model that throws the fault.  Pointers are initialized.  Array's could be messed up somewhere, but like I said, weird it only gets thrown on this model.

Comment: Well it might be that you do the same error for all of the models. But only the memory location of the 5th model will result in this segmentation fault. You can cross the rail way four times in a row when the signals are red and the trains is driving up without something happening and the 5th time it will hit you because it was to close.

Comment: Don't get hit by trains, got it.  Guess I'll start looking at my arrays.  Thanks.